# Upgrade user to skip using sudo to write files

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sudo

I need to run a Capistrano recipe to setup some services so I have to be able to write to /etc/init without prefixing my command with sudo.

How can I make an Ubuntu user abel to write to /etc/init without requiring sudo?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue with using sudo ? you could setup sudo to be passwordless for certain commands for certain users so that you could still use sudo within a script.

Comment: No issue with sudo, this is a better solution. How can I achieve so? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not recommending or suggesting this as it has security implications, but you have at least a couple of options:

1. `sudo chown -R  username /etc/init` will change the owner of everything in init to 
   username so they can then write to it  or
2. Change the permissions and group for the files - `chmod -R 775 /etc/init`  to change
   the permissions to allow group to do whatever it wants, `chgrp -R groupname /etc/init`
   to change the group the files are in and then add the user to the appropriate group
   (I do this by editing /etc/group directly , but there are no doubt other ways)

Comment: Directly editing /etc/group is risky, you can mess up the syntax and break something. `gpasswd -a username groupname` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting up `sudo` to be passwordless for a certain user, so that the user can run certain commands with `sudo` to do what you need.

Adding the following to `/etc/sudoers` will allow user `scriptuser` to run the `runscript` command (off the top of my head - will check later)

```
Cmnd_Alias commands = runscript
scriptuser ALL=NOPASSWD:commands
```

Comment: If I try to add it using Capistrano I get ```cannot create /etc/sudoers: Permission denied``` I have also tried to prefix the echo commands with sudo but same result.

Comment: what user is running the Capistrano Recipe ? You need to add that user, and the command that user runs when you run capistrano.

Comment: I have added that user (deployer) and the command (bundle) but I cannot create the file ```permission denied```